# Parsing a dictionary into many values and making a table in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, python-requests

I am trying to use the Scopus API to retrieve the unique author identifier number assigned to an author by scopus. In some cases, a name will yield multiple author IDs. My trouble is in reading the json format so that I may parse out the 'dc:identifiers'

Here is my code:

```
    import requests
    import json

    url = "http://api.elsevier.com/content/search/author"

    querystring = {"apiKey":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx","query":["AUTHLASTNAME(Volaire)","AUTHFIRST(F)"]}

    headers = {
   'cache-control': "no-cache",
   'postman-token': "5c0df5ad-2645-8e88-0f8a-10795757b4ec"
    }

   response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

   results = response.json()
```

I then get the following output:

```
{
  "search-results": {
    "opensearch:totalResults": "3",
    "opensearch:startIndex": "0",
    "opensearch:itemsPerPage": "3",
    "opensearch:Query": {
      "@role": "request",
      "@searchTerms": "AUTHLASTNAME(Volaire)",
      "@startPage": "0"
    },
    "link": [
      {
        "@_fa": "true",
        "@href": "http://api.elsevier.com/content/search/author?start=0&count=25&query=AUTHLASTNAME%28Volaire%29&apiKey=4275854a6db51fb373ef69fb1337ccf9",
        "@ref": "self",
        "@type": "application/json"
      },
      {
        "@_fa": "true",
        "@href": "http://api.elsevier.com/content/search/author?start=0&count=25&query=AUTHLASTNAME%28Volaire%29&apiKey=4275854a6db51fb373ef69fb1337ccf9",
        "@ref": "first",
        "@type": "application/json"
      }
    ],
    "entry": [
      {
        "@_fa": "true",
        "link": [
          {
            "@_fa": "true",
            "@href": "http://api.elsevier.com/content/author/author_id/55910750900",
            "@ref": "self"
          },
          {
            "@_fa": "true",
            "@href": "http://api.elsevier.com/content/search/author?query=au-id%2855910750900%29",
            "@ref": "search"
          },
          {
            "@_fa": "true",
            "@href": "https://www.scopus.com/author/citedby.uri?partnerID=HzOxMe3b&citedAuthorId=55910750900&origin=inward",
            "@ref": "scopus-citedby"
          },
          {
            "@_fa": "true",
            "@href": "https://www.scopus.com/authid/detail.uri?partnerID=HzOxMe3b&authorId=55910750900&origin=inward",
            "@ref": "scopus-author"
          }
        ],
        "prism:url": "http://api.elsevier.com/content/author/author_id/55910750900",
        "dc:identifier": "AUTHOR_ID:55910750900",
        "eid": "9-s2.0-55910750900",
        "preferred-name": {
          "surname": "Volaire",
          "given-name": "Florence A.",
          "initials": "F.A."
        },
        "name-variant": [
          {
            "@_fa": "true",
            "surname": "Volaire",
            "given-name": "F.",
            "initials": "F."
          },
          {
            "@_fa": "true",
            "surname": "Volaire",
            "given-name": "Florence",
            "initials": "F."
          }
        ],
        "document-count": "41",
        "subject-area": [
          {
            "@abbrev": "ENVI",
            "@frequency": "7",
            "$": "Environmental Science (all)"
          },
          {
            "@abbrev": "AGRI",
            "@frequency": "50",
            "$": "Agricultural and Biological Sciences (all)"
          },
          {
            "@abbrev": "ENGI",
            "@frequency": "4",
            "$": "Engineering (all)"
          }
        ],
        "affiliation-current": {
          "affiliation-url": "http://api.elsevier.com/content/affiliation/affiliation_id/60020315",
          "affiliation-id": "60020315",
          "affiliation-name": "INRA Institut National de La Recherche Agronomique",
          "affiliation-city": "Paris",
          "affiliation-country": "France"
        }
      },
      {
        "@_fa": "true",
        "link": [
          {
            "@_fa": "true",
            "@href": "http://api.elsevier.com/content/author/author_id/6603570012",
            "@ref": "self"
          },
          {
            "@_fa": "true",
            "@href": "http://api.elsevier.com/content/search/author?query=au-id%286603570012%29",
            "@ref": "search"
          },
          {
            "@_fa": "true",
            "@href": "https://www.scopus.com/author/citedby.uri?partnerID=HzOxMe3b&citedAuthorId=6603570012&origin=inward",
            "@ref": "scopus-citedby"
          },
          {
            "@_fa": "true",
            "@href": "https://www.scopus.com/authid/detail.uri?partnerID=HzOxMe3b&authorId=6603570012&origin=inward",
            "@ref": "scopus-author"
          }
        ],
        "prism:url": "http://api.elsevier.com/content/author/author_id/6603570012",
        "dc:identifier": "AUTHOR_ID:6603570012",
        "eid": "9-s2.0-6603570012",
        "preferred-name": {
          "surname": "Volaire",
          "given-name": "Florence",
          "initials": "F."
        },
        "name-variant": [
          {
            "@_fa": "true",
            "surname": "Volaire",
            "given-name": "F.",
            "initials": "F."
          }
        ],
        "document-count": "8",
        "subject-area": [
          {
            "@abbrev": "AGRI",
            "@frequency": "13",
            "$": "Agricultural and Biological Sciences (all)"
          },
          {
            "@abbrev": "BIOC",
            "@frequency": "1",
            "$": "Biochemistry, Genetics and Molecular Biology (all)"
          }
        ],
        "affiliation-current": {
          "affiliation-url": "http://api.elsevier.com/content/affiliation/affiliation_id/60020315",
          "affiliation-id": "60020315",
          "affiliation-name": "INRA Institut National de La Recherche Agronomique",
          "affiliation-city": "Paris",
          "affiliation-country": "France"
        }
      },
      {
        "@_fa": "true",
        "link": [
          {
            "@_fa": "true",
            "@href": "http://api.elsevier.com/content/author/author_id/24571987100",
            "@ref": "self"
          },
          {
            "@_fa": "true",
            "@href": "http://api.elsevier.com/content/search/author?query=au-id%2824571987100%29",
            "@ref": "search"
          },
          {
            "@_fa": "true",
            "@href": "https://www.scopus.com/author/citedby.uri?partnerID=HzOxMe3b&citedAuthorId=24571987100&origin=inward",
            "@ref": "scopus-citedby"
          },
          {
            "@_fa": "true",
            "@href": "https://www.scopus.com/authid/detail.uri?partnerID=HzOxMe3b&authorId=24571987100&origin=inward",
            "@ref": "scopus-author"
          }
        ],
        "prism:url": "http://api.elsevier.com/content/author/author_id/24571987100",
        "dc:identifier": "AUTHOR_ID:24571987100",
        "eid": "9-s2.0-24571987100",
        "preferred-name": {
          "surname": "Volaire",
          "given-name": "M.",
          "initials": "M."
        },
        "name-variant": [
          {
            "@_fa": "true",
            "surname": "Volaire",
            "given-name": null,
            "initials": "M."
          }
        ],
        "document-count": "1",
        "subject-area": [
          {
            "@abbrev": "CHEM",
            "@frequency": "2",
            "$": "Chemistry (all)"
          },
          {
            "@abbrev": "BIOC",
            "@frequency": "1",
            "$": "Biochemistry, Genetics and Molecular Biology (all)"
          },
          {
            "@abbrev": "ENVI",
            "@frequency": "1",
            "$": "Environmental Science (all)"
          }
```

1. What I need to do is parse this so that I get the 'dc:identifiers' that are pulled up. In this instance there are 3.
2. Ideally I would like to put this into an table where I have 
   AUTHLASTNAME / AUTHFIRST / DCIDENTIFER (in columns)

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: The posted code has nothing to do with the question (about processing the data it produced); is this correct?

Comment: @ScottHunter: that's correct, except it tells you how I arrived at the json output.

Comment: How you got the data isn't relevant; and the output you posted is incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get the info for part 1:

```
print( [e["dc:identifier"] for e in results['search-results']['entry']] )
```

You can use something similar for other information from each `entry`.

As for part 2: python doesn't have tables.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?
what you have here is on track :)

```
print(results['search-results']['link']['entry']['dc:identifier'])
```

try this. It should work because the values you want are inside objects inside a list in your json.

```
some_dict = [
    { 
        "dc:identifiers": r['dc:identifier'], 
        "AUTHLASTNAME":  r['preferred-name']['surname'],
        "AUTHFIRST":  r['preferred-name']['given-name'],
    } for r in results['search-results']['entry']
]
```

Obviously that is assuming your json stays in that format. 
Also check that I put results['search-results']['entry'] is actually correct. I did not triple check it

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting this: "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing"

Comment: I guess the [search-results][entry] is the part that is confusing to me, because it's too many objects within lists...